# embedding pascal

Tags: scripting, pascal, embedding

Is anyone aware of a Pascal interpreter/compiler which is embeddable in C++ (or anything else other than Pascal) applications? I am cloning (for lack of a better word) an application which uses an Object-Pascal compatible scripting language and needs to be script compatible. Am I going to end up writing an interpreter? (!)

Comment: So, do you want the Pascal to execute as a runtime script (like a Visual Basic script) or as a compiled library (DLL or .so) that is dynamically loaded, plugin-style?  I.e. are you wanting to interpret Pascal at runtime (like Tcl or Scheme), or compile it and execute the binary?

Answer (score 2):

There's [RemObjects Pascal Script](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx). You can probably call it from [C++ Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder).

> Pascal Script is a free scripting
>   engine that allows you to use most of
>   the Object Pascal language within your
>   Delphi or Free Pascal projects at
>   runtime.

There's also [TMS Scripter Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudio.asp).

> By building scripting support into your applications, you can provide a high degree of configurability, flexibility and automation control in your applications.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is about interpreter/compiler of a language for application user to program and run, if it is the case I may suggest [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) or [Pascal Script](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx).
Sorry for lack of links, but points are required for that.

EDIT: Fixed links and Lua spelling

Answer (score 1):

PaxCompiler can be embedded in C++ Builder. More info at http://www.paxcompiler.com.

Answer (score 0):

[NIH Image](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frsb.info.nih.gov%2Fnih-image%2F&ei=8rGmS7fVHJK1tgfDir2UCg&usg=AFQjCNEkd8oHmZBx46ns1BzFwTqIhVHL3g) had a pascal like embedded language. Don't know if it is available, easily extractable, or useful for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) compiler supports Object Pascal and it says [you can call a Pascal library from a C program](http://community.freepascal.org:10000/docs-html/prog/progse55.html#x244-24500012.4).  With luck this will be as good as embedding.

That what you're looking for?  (If not, you can translate Standard Pascal to C with 
[`p2c`](http://packages.debian.org/source/lenny/p2c), a Pascal-to-C translator that is available from Debian, among other places. But having used `p2c`, I can't recommend it, and I don't think it understands Object Pascal.)

Comment: Not even close! Note that FPC is mostly GCC callable. If it is callable from other C compilers depends on their abilities

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/BenLand100/CPascal

You can extend it for what ever you are trying to build.